# simplexml.class.php in PHPEclipse doesn't exist

Tags: php, xml, eclipse

I just installed PHPEclipse on my Eclipse Luna. I had a site project that I imported to Eclipse. Trying to manipulate an XML(addChild) file I used the folowing code :

```
if (isset($_POST['submitSave'])) {
    require 'simplexml.class.php';
    $racine = simplexml_load_file($fichier);
    $annonce = $racine->addChild('annonce');
    $annonce->addAttribute('id', $_POST['id']);
    $annonce->addChild('ref', $_POST['ref']);
    $annonce->addChild('image', $_POST['image']);
    $annonce->addChild('entete', $_POST['entete']);
    $annonce->addChild('nouveau', $_POST['nouveau']);
    $annonce->addChild('detail', $_POST['description']);
    file_put_contents($fichier, $racine->asXML());
    header('location : parm-annonce.php');                          
}
```

But unfortunately I have an error :

Include filename : simplexml.class.php doesn't exist in the project. 
**I can't find an issue.**

I have installed XAMPP as described here - http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/hfoss/wiki/How_to_Setup_Eclipse_with_XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need line #2

```
require 'simplexml.class.php';
```

SimpleXMLElement class is available by default.

Comment: This isn't always true, by the way. E.g. on Cygwin, you need to install it separately.